# '_beginthreadex()' is overriding my global 'Unhandled Exception Filter'

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, exception, msvcrt

I want my application to create a *dump file* whenever an *un-handled exception* does occur.

For this I am using the `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter()` function from *Windows*, supplying it with my own *Exception Filter callback function* that should be called whenever any thread fails to handle an exception. My callback is creating the dump-file and **most of the time this will work fine**.

The problem is that sometimes my *Exception Filter callback function* **is not being called** even though an un-handled exception **did occur**.

After some debugging I found out the reason for this:
`_beginthreadex()` implementation in `Visual Studio 2012` will handle any un-handled exception from *this* thread:

Code from `Visual Studio 2012`, 'thread.c' - Implementation of `_beginthreadex()`:

```
__try
{
    ( (void(__CLRCALL_OR_CDECL *)(void *))(((_ptiddata)ptd)->_initaddr) )
        ( ((_ptiddata)ptd)->_initarg );

    _endthread();
}
__except ( _XcptFilter(GetExceptionCode(), GetExceptionInformation()) )
{
        /*
            * Should never reach here
            */
        _exit( GetExceptionCode() );

} /* end of _try - _except */
```

*[BTW - this is the same for `_beginthread()` and `_beginthreadex()`]*

As we can see, in the case of un-handled exception, the code will:

1. Catch the exception,
2. [Maybe will issue a message-box to the end-user],
3. **Terminate the application by calling `_exit()`**,

By doing this `_beginthreadex()` is actually **masking out** my global exception handler code...

*My Question:*
How I can verify that my *Exception Filter callback function* **is always being called** in the case of un-handled exception, even for threads that were created by the `_beginthread()`/`_beginthreadex()`?

Thanks for any tip, PazO

Comment: Technically there is no unhandled exception, because it *is* handled. So why would your filter get it? Why not add a try-catch block to your thread function? Then you would surely get the exception just before returning to this code.

Comment: Just use CreateThread instead.

Comment: @BoPersson: My application is a wide company project with many different bits of code spawning threads using the '_beginthreadex' API. Modifying each location is very sizific and error-prone.

Comment: @Harry: It is widely documented that the Win32 'CreateThread' should not be called directly as it does not initialize c-runtime library code for this thread.

Comment: @PazO: that hasn't been true for several decades.  Unfortunately, the documentation hasn't caught up, but if CreateThread didn't work with C the Windows thread pool would be pretty much useless.  (For completeness: if you're statically linking the C runtime *and* running on Windows XP or earlier, using CreateThread results in a very small resource leak.)